# Why won't the following keyboard shortcut work for a Resharper action on VS 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, keyboard-shortcuts, resharper

Although it most likely doesn't have anything to do with resharper... here's my setup:

- VS2010 Ultimate 10.0.31319.1
- JetBrains Resharper 5.1 (C# Edition 5.1.1727.12)

I've configured the shortcut via VS2010 Tools > Options > Keyboard > C# Scheme

> Command     **Resharper_UnitTestSession_RunAll**
>   Shortcut    **Ctrl+Alt+\ (Global)**
>   Use new shortcut in       **Global**

Now I open a unit test session using Resharper. I see the little "Run All Tests" button (in the toolwindow) has a tooltip which says (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>\</kbd>). But the shortcut only works if the focus is within the Unit Test Session toolwindow.

I'd like it to work (at the bare minimum) from the text editor which is where I spend the most editor. But for some reason, it just won't work.

Maybe I am tired and someone else can point out what I am missing...

Answer (score 1):

Set the `ReSharper_Resharper_UnitTest_RunSolution` to that shortcut, instead.
That will run all the tests in the solution - presumably what you're trying to do.

I didn't find much use for the `Resharper_UnitTestSession_RunAll` option, as I've usually just changed some code when I want to run the tests.

Hope this helps.